# AS3 "RSAKey" equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

First sorry for my bad English.

I have to use a similar class to [RSAKey](http://www.adventeer.com/map/_RSA/RSAKey.as), from hurlan in C#, but I can't find anything similar, and I don't really understand what exactly this class does.

Do you know any equivalent to this (per example in BouncyCastle), or can you explain me what it exactly does?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question platform, not an education one! Do you have a question according a certain coding problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Oh i'm really sorry... I'm new on StackOverflow and i didn't knew about this. Sorry.

I tried with BouncyCastle and RSACryptoServiceProvider (.net Framework), but I don't have the same results. The function that I want to reproduce is the "verify"

Answer (score 3):

Read more about RSA [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29). It's a public key encryption protocol. (read [What is public key crytography ?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_key))

In C#, you have to use :

- With .Net 4.5 : [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- With WinRT : [AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already know what is RSA. Are you sure that the "RSAKey" class do only an RSA encryption?

Comment: No it doesn't. It can also do key generation and signing. But the two classes linked in my answer do it too ;)

Comment: What are searching for, precisely ?

Comment: I'll try to explain it.

So I have a RSA key wich seems to be "decrypted" with this class with a another key (with the function verify)

Comment: I confirm, no problem with functions that I gave you ;)